# Slow ping while using ssh on a server in another continent

Tags: ssh, ping, pycharm

So I am coding (using pycharm) connected via ssh to a server which is in another continent and the ping is very high. Because of that, everything that I do takes a lot of time.
Is there anything that can be done to solve this problem?

Here is the output of traceroute

```
traceroute to 89.171.107.238 (89.171.107.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  3.706 ms  3.665 ms  3.639 ms
 2  172.20.50.1 (172.20.50.1)  5.765 ms  6.837 ms  7.245 ms
 3  customer-45-6-164-21.cmctelecom.com.br (45.6.164.21)  5.462 ms  5.600 ms  5.714 ms
 4  customer-45-6-167-2.cmctelecom.com.br (45.6.167.2)  7.204 ms  7.514 ms  7.285 ms
 5  198.18.1.141 (198.18.1.141)  9.643 ms  9.750 ms  9.623 ms
 6  100.110.115.78 (100.110.115.78)  8.773 ms  5.059 ms  7.623 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  100.127.6.154 (100.127.6.154)  5.778 ms  5.768 ms  5.759 ms
10  et-0-0-1-0.monet.border-b.bct.algartelecom.com.br (168.197.23.193)  108.200 ms  108.190 ms  112.541 ms
11  38.142.192.193 (38.142.192.193)  114.732 ms  114.720 ms  114.710 ms
12  be3454.ccr21.mia01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.85.113)  115.551 ms be3455.ccr22.mia01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.85.129)  114.628 ms  114.605 ms
13  be3482.ccr41.atl01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.24.145)  126.460 ms  129.097 ms  126.639 ms
14  be2113.ccr42.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.24.221)  126.578 ms be2112.ccr41.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.7.157)  127.396 ms be2113.ccr42.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.24.221)  126.557 ms
15  be2807.ccr42.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.40.109)  127.701 ms  335.427 ms  335.393 ms
16  be2317.ccr41.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.30.186)  340.754 ms be2490.ccr42.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.42.86)  340.685 ms  340.648 ms
17  be12488.ccr42.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.51.42)  348.811 ms be12194.ccr41.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.56.94)  340.580 ms  340.545 ms
18  be2815.ccr41.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.206)  340.511 ms  340.476 ms be2816.ccr42.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.38.210)  340.442 ms
19  be2484.ccr21.waw01.atlas.cogentco.com (130.117.51.105)  340.480 ms  340.446 ms  340.411 ms
20  149.6.70.30 (149.6.70.30)  340.375 ms netia.demarc.cogentco.com (149.6.70.50)  340.339 ms 149.6.70.66 (149.6.70.66)  340.227 ms
21  83.238.248.19 (83.238.248.19)  340.272 ms  2262.730 ms  2262.661 ms
22  * * *
23  warsf024rt01.inetia.pl (87.204.224.19)  2262.520 ms  2262.484 ms  2262.450 ms
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

And this is the output of ping:

```
PING 89.171.107.238 (89.171.107.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=2 ttl=239 time=1026 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=3 ttl=239 time=892 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=5 ttl=239 time=352 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=6 ttl=239 time=248 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=8 ttl=239 time=418 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=9 ttl=239 time=1018 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=10 ttl=239 time=1005 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=11 ttl=239 time=1043 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=12 ttl=239 time=282 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=13 ttl=239 time=1031 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=14 ttl=239 time=368 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=15 ttl=239 time=1017 ms
64 bytes from 89.171.107.238: icmp_seq=16 ttl=239 time=603 ms
```

Comment: It could be helpful if you expanded upon your use case. The more details you provide, the easier it is for people to help you reach a better solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I am not very experienced so Im not sure which details are relevant. I used to work normally at home, when I was in the same country as the server. But I am spending some days in another country and the latency increased a lot. I use ubuntu, and I connect to the server via vpn. Then I mount locally file systems from the server and use pycharm to edit and run code that is on the server.

Comment: What latency do you get (ie what does ping repirt).  Can you provide the output of a teaceroute or MTR as well?  Are latencies similar with and without vpn?  Do latencies change significantly during times of the day or depending on what else is going on on your network.

Comment: Hi! I added the outputs of ping and traceroute. I didnt notice meaningfull differences with/without vpn and across the day

Comment: Unfourtunately, all your latency is at the far end of the connection, which is not unexpected, but it does mean that you have little recourse. changing ISPs might help, but its more likely not to. The major latency spike in your traceroute is when the traffic passes from Cogent to Netia. The further away the problem is, the less likely things you can do locally will have any impact. any real fix would require changes at the remote end.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your IDE on the remote server? If yes, you should expect it to be slow. Try mounting a source directory over the network (say, NFS, SSHFS, among many many options, even manually using scp if you only change 1 or 2 files) and edit your source code locally and only use the remote server to execute and test.

Comment: Hi! yes I do that. I mount the file system locally and run the IDE on there. However even opening it with the file explorer takes one or two seconds. When I ping the server i get something around 300 and 1200ms.

Comment: You likely need to come up eith a different paradigm for eorking - like having a local copy which you work on an then mirror/deploy to the live site periodically.  There are a range of ways you can do this from simple semi-manual to robust automated deployments. The bottom line is often you cant force latency down, you need to alter your workflow.  Also  its worth commenting if your latency is highly variable there is congestion somewhere - in that case of mote bandwidth, a different isp or vpn or qos may mitigate the issue.

Comment: You can get almost anywhere connected in less then 400ms (less then 350ms really) if the connections are not congested - so your approach may be different depending on the $$$ you have to solve the problem and if this latency is "good enough". (for intensive interactive ssh its likely not)

Comment: If you are already mounting the file system and running IDE locally, the problem maybe related to your IDE not optimized for slow file system. Check if there is something you can turn off, like background indexing, etc. Try using a simpler IDE, start with basics, like text editors, etc.